# is it possible to copy s3 bucket content from one bucket to another account s3 bucket without using bucket policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, policy

I want to copy the S3 bucket object to a different account, but the requirement can't use the Bucket policy,
then is it possible to copy content from one bucket to another without using the bucket policy?

Comment: All you need is the ability to download the files from the source and upload the files to the destination - no bucket policy required (unless the bucket policy explicitly deny's you). The easiest way to copy files between buckets is with the AWS CLI. Are you able to create IAM users/roles/policies and API keys, launch ec2 instances, do you have/can you create a user/role with permissions to access both S3 locations? Also, how many/big are your files. And ive got to ask - why cant you edit the bucket policy? Please edit your question and expand it.

Comment: Are you unable to create a Bucket Policy in _both_ accounts, or would it be possible to do this in _one_ account?

Comment: I have created a bucket policy in the source account and after adding the bucket policy it's working, 

but the requirement is can't use any policy or IAM role, so without an IAM role it's working but without policy how I can do that's my question...

Comment: Hello, @MisterSmith the requirement is we have to copy s3 bucket content from Source to the destination i.e. from one s3 bucket to another s3 bucket which is in a different account.
The mentioned activity is supposed to be done without creating any "bucket policy" & "IAM Role".
I want to understand that is it possible? or any alternative way to perform this activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install AWS CLI,
run AWS configure set source bucket credentials as default and,
visit https://github.com/Shi191099/S3-Copy-old-data-without-Policy.git

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use [native S3 object replication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/replication.html) between different accounts without using a bucket policy. As stated in the [permissions documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/setting-repl-config-perm-overview.html):

> When the source and destination buckets aren't owned by the same accounts, the owner of the destination bucket must also add a bucket policy to grant the owner of the source bucket permissions to perform replication actions

You could write a custom application that uses IAM roles to replicate objects, but this will likely be quite involved as you'll need to track the state of the bucket and all of the objects written to it.